# Best location for bash script to run with cron

Tags: cron

I have spent the better part of yesterday trying to set up a cron task to run a bash script. My bash script 'crunchy.sh' is set to be executable. It contains the shebang and the path to the npm module that the command calls. I currently have my bash script under /media/jola/Data/tasks on an external drive that is mounted automatically at start up, the drive is called 'Data'. I have reviewed the syslog to see the CMD /media/jola/Data/tasks/crunchy.sh is being called, but nothing happens. My bash script runs perfectly as such, './crunchy.sh'. Should the bash script be placed under /home/jola on OS HDD for use with cron? Contents of crunchy.sh:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules:/media/jola/Data/anime
 crunchy -u xx -p xx -e 80 http://www.crunchyroll.com/dragon-ball-super
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the `crunchy.sh` file contents? I think the answer to your question is "No".

Comment: Can you check that it's not a `$PATH` issue as explained in [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2409369)? If you `echo $PATH`as which ever user will be running cron and then copy the results into the Bash script it may work. It shouldn't matter where you put the script file either, to answer that part of your question.

Comment: I have added the content of crunchy.sh. Also, here is the path when 'echo $PATH' is run: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/loc

Comment: this is what shows in syslog: 'jola@RaspberryMate:/var/log$ `grep "dbz" syslog
Mar  6 19:05:01 RaspberryMate CRON[20709]: (jola) CMD (/media/jola/Data/anime/dbzcrunchy.sh)`

Comment: @DougSmythies Update made.

Comment: I got it to work. My suspicion is that the path was wrong. When I `echo $PATH` I added that to my PATH variable in script. Thank You!